# VBA how to Clear the content of an unknown Range?

Tags: excel, vba

The casual method is `Sheet.Range("A3:C3").clearcontents`  For example.

For my program, the number 3 comes from somewhere else, lets say `Inputbox`.

```
Dim Index As Integer

Index = Inputbox.....value

Sheet.Range("A Index : "C Index).clearcontents         'Dont work
```

so i dont know what value Index is going to get yet, how can clear with a Range then?

Later i want to copy that range and paste it some where else with Range.

do you have an alternative, should i use `Cells( Index, 1).clear`

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use the right syntax for the range address: `Range("A" & Index & ":C" & Index)`, though using Cells is certainly reasonable as well.

Comment: `Sheet.Cells(Index, "C").Resize(1, 3).clearcontents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sheet.Range("A" & index & ":C" & index).ClearContents